# React Component not Rerending When Updating State Array

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to update an array that is in state on a functional component. I have tried making a copy of the array... pushing to the copy... and then setArray(newarray)...

The array is not updating on screen or in console.log until the NEXT update to the array. So, I am always one array item behind. This is on React Native by the way, using Typescript.

Am I doing something wrong here? How do I get componentDidUpdate to trigger when the state array is modified?

Here is the code I am using:

```
const [currentNumber, setCurrentNumber] = useState<string[]>([]);

const numberAppended = (number: string) => {
        setCurrentNumber(currentNumber => [...currentNumber, number])
}
```

I've also tried

```
  const [currentNumber, setCurrentNumber] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const numberAppended = (number: string) => {
        let newCurrentNumber = [...currentNumber];
        newCurrentNumber.push(number);
        setCurrentNumber(newCurrentNumber);
}
```

Comment: Did you try to add useEffect with currentNumber as dependency? your code looks OK

Comment: it might have something to do with the way you call the function may be ? can you show more code ?